# configuration faliure after replaceing chrome driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I m working on automation using selenium webdriver. my chrome driver got  crashed suddenly when i run the test. Then i remove chromedriver.exe and download latest one and replace on Target folder and  driver folder. rebuild the project and ran again.project is building without errors. but chrome is not open.
It throws error as follws :

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod openBrowser([Ljava.lang.Object;@15bbf42f)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;

couldn't figure out where is the error. appreciate your support.

Find before class code :

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void openBrowser(Object[] testArgs) throws Exception {
        try {
            logInstruction("LOG INSTRUCTION: Open the browser");
            String dateTime;
            File downLoadDir;
            Date date;
            DateFormat dateFormat;
            String dateExe = getDate();
            writeToOutPut("===================");
            writeToOutPut(dateExe);

            switch (browser) {

                case FIREFOX:
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    profile.setPreference(
                            "capability.policy.default.Window.QueryInterface",
                            "allAccess");
                    profile.setPreference(
                            "capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get",
                            "allAccess");
                    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
                    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
                    profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
                    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpegï¿½");
                    //profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
                    uiDriver = new DefaultUIDriver(profile);
                    break;
                    case CHROME:
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
                    options.addArguments("test-type");
                    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
           Field f = options.getClass().getDeclaredField("experimentalOptions");
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    Map<String, Object> expOpts = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(options);
                    expOpts.put("prefs", settings);

                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

                    uiDriver = new DefaultUIDriver(capabilities);
                   // downloadPath = "/AutomationChromeDownloads/" + dateTime;
                    break;

                case INTERNETEXPLORER:
                    downloadPath = config.getValue("defaultDownLoadPath_IE");

                    uiDriver = new DefaultUIDriver(Browser.INTERNETEXPLORER);

                    break;
            }
            uiDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            startURL = (String) testArgs[1];
            uiDriver.get(startURL);
            uiDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

[find the image to find error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oEFx.png)

Comment: Provide your beforeMethod code portion.

Comment: @optimis_creeper updated the problem with code

Comment: before method i didnt do any change ... it should not be the issue as i guess .